# Excel or VBA code to match all data in two tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I have a open position (JobClass) I enter as a search value (i.e. 5077).  In the same row I have all the other lower level positions (Job Classes) that could apply for that position based on skills and job requirements.

I can match the search value (JobClass) and return all the applicable codes listed in the same row, but my problem is trying to get a formula or VBA code that will search the returned list of codes in the employee roaster and return personnel that are currently holding the retrieved codes and their information.

Table data:
[image: Table data]

Comment: Hi, can you please post sample data and the expected result for that data? How are you matching the search value and returning all the applicable codes listed in the same row? Where are you encountering a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Surely you mean "column" when you say "in the same row" so I will proceed assuming that.

Your output table needs several things, the first of which, the bottom rung from which all other things rise, is that list of other acceptable JobClass entries. So in that column of the output table, place a formula that return that list of JobClass data:

```
=FILTER(HLOOKUP(JobClass,SearchTable,SEQUENCE(13,1,4,1),FALSE),HLOOKUP(JobClass,SearchTable,SEQUENCE(13,1,4,1),FALSE)<>0)
```

It assumes you create two ranges, one being `JobClass` which would be the criteria cell labeled that, or use its cell address instead, and definitely a range called `SearchTable` here which would include all the columns headed with a `JobClass` entry and all the rows from the entry down to the "Code13" line.

The `HLOOKUP()` looks across the first row for the criteria's JobClass value, finds it, then reads the 4th through 16th rows. `FILTER()` removes the cells that are empty from the results. Searching for "5023" would return 6 results. "5077" returns 13.

Once that column of the lower table is populated, you can consider the Code column to its left. This is addressed by generating up to 13 numbers (1-13) AS NEEDED, unless you'd like them all filled. The following formula will do that neatly:

```
=FILTER(SEQUENCE(13),B33:B45<>"")
```

which uses `FILTER()` to create a list of 13 numbers (1-13) and examine the column of JobClass return for "not-blank" values returning only that many of the list of numbers. So any lines that do not have a JobClass have no Code entry either.

If one wants it filled even if 1 or 6 items are in the JobClass column, then just the `SEQUENCE()` part of the formula is needed.

That gives you 1,2,3,...,13. Format the column like this:  `"Code"#0` and Excel will display those numbers with the word "Code" preceding them.

The remainder of the information is just simple `HLOOKUP()`'s based on the JobClass criterion. They just need to return either the 2nd or 3rd part of the column found so like so:

```
=HLOOKUP(JobClass,SearchTable,2,false)
```

and

```
=HLOOKUP(JobClass,SearchTable,3,false)
```

As the rest of your data in that table comes from other sources, I leave those things to you.